# How to create a modal window which only masks a particular component in ExtJs 4?

Tags: javascript, extjs, window, modal-dialog, extjs4

I would like to create a modal window which will only mask the center region of my application.
How can I achieve this?

In ExtJs 3 I was able to use the windows `renderTo` property and render the window to the center region. So that when the window was shown only the center region was masked.

However if I use the `renderTo` property in ExtJs 4 the whole document.body is masked. And in IE the whole the window is also masked.

Below is the border layout example from the Ext Examples. with a modal window in the center region. ( the whole body gets masked when shown)

```
  Ext.onReady(function() {
var cw;

Ext.create('Ext.Viewport', {
    layout: {
        type: 'border',
        padding: 5
    },
    defaults: {
        split: true
    },
    items: [{
        region: 'north',
        collapsible: true,
        title: 'North',
        split: true,
        height: 100,
        html: 'north'
    },{
        region: 'west',
        collapsible: true,
        title: 'Starts at width 30%',
        split: true,
        width: '30%',
        html: 'west<br>I am floatable'
    },{
        region: 'center',
        layout: 'border',
        border: false,
        items: [{
            region: 'center',
            html: 'center center',
            title: 'Center',
            items: [cw = Ext.create('Ext.Window', {
                xtype: 'window',
                closable: false,
                minimizable: true,
                title: 'Constrained Window',
                height: 200,
                modal: true, //MODAL WINDOW, MASKS THE WHOLE DOCUMENT BODY?
                width: 400,
                constrain: true,
                html: 'I am in a Container',
                itemId: 'center-window',
                minimize: function() {
                    this.floatParent.down('button#toggleCw').toggle();
                }
            })],
            dockedItems: [{
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                dock: 'bottom',
                items: ['Text followed by a spacer',
                    ' ', {
                        itemId: 'toggleCw',
                        text: 'Constrained Window',
                        enableToggle: true,
                        toggleHandler: function() {
                        cw.setVisible(!cw.isVisible());
                    }
                }]
            }]
        },{
            region: 'south',
            height: 100,
            split: true,
            collapsible: true,
            title: 'Splitter above me',
            html: 'center south'
        }]
    },{
        region: 'east',
        collapsible: true,
        floatable: true,
        split: true,
        width: 200,
        title: 'East',
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox',
            padding: 5,
            align: 'stretch'
        },
        items: [{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Text field'
        }, {
            xtype: 'component',
            html: 'I am floatable'
        }]
    },{
        region: 'south',
        collapsible: true,
        split: true,
        height: 200,
        title: 'South',
        layout: {
            type: 'border',
            padding: 5
        },
        items: [{
            title: 'South Central',
            region: 'center',
            html: 'South Central'
        }, {
            title: 'South Eastern',
            region: 'east',
            flex: 1,
            html: 'South Eastern',
            split: true,
            collapsible: true
        }, {
            title: 'South Western',
            region: 'west',
            flex: 1,
            html: 'South Western<br>I collapse to nothing',
            split: true,
            collapsible: true,
            collapseMode: 'mini'
        }]
    }]
});
});
```

Comment: IMHO, question needs clarification. By definition, modal disallows you from interacting with its 'parent'. visual 'masking' is just Ext's eye candy. so are you saying you want a non modal dialog that masks certain area/components in the parent? or are you still saying you want modal but the parent should not be visually masked except for certain regions/components?

Comment: @AMOL: I have rephrased my question. What I want to do is render a window to a container so that when that window is shown only the parent container is masked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two ways...

Via the component's ID:

`Ext.getCmp('componentId').getEl().mask()`

Or via the element's ID:

`Ext.get('elementId').mask()`

I'm guessing that the first one is what you'll need. You can just bind it to an event listener on the window...

```
listeners: {
    'show': function() {
        Ext.getCmp('componentId').getEl().mask();
    },
    'hide': function() {
        Ext.getCmp('componentId').getEl().unmask();
    }
}
```

EDIT:

As described in the ExtJS 4.0.2 API docs... modal masks everything behind the Window, not just it's parent...

> True to make the window modal and mask everything behind it when displayed, false to display it without restricting access to other UI elements (defaults to false).

Comment: @Jaitsu: How will this work for a modal window? As the modal window will mask the whole body?

Comment: toggle `modal: false` so it doesn't mask anything, and then just use the code above to mask the element/component you wish

Comment: @Jaitsu: So is this a bug with the Ext code?. Or is this the correct way to do this?

Comment: It's not a bug, the idea of "modal" is to prevent interaction with **all** other elements, so it masks it. In your case you just wanted to mask a specific element and hence the code to do so

Comment: I understand. But I thought "modal" would mask only the windows parent container. For example I want to render a window to a specific tab in a tab panel and mask that panel. So that I can open more tabs but that window will always remain relative to the first tab it was rendered to, and not display in other tabs.

Comment: AFAIK no, because an Ext.Window renders to the document's body

Answer (score 4):

You can add modal window not to the whole viewport, but to the 'center' region only. In this case only this region will be masked. There are some code:

```
var window = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    title: 'Hello',
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    modal: true
});

this.getViewport().child('[region=center]').add(window);
window.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

use `renderTo` ctor param

expample:

```
dialog = new Ext.ux.AnimateWindow({
    renderTo: App.FeedPanel.el.dom.firstElementChild.firstElementChild,
    modal: true,
    title: "Add Feed Source",
    closable: true,
    resizable: false,
    width: 350,
    items: [form]
});
```